# Every infinite set has a not compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X \subset R^n$ an infinite set. There is $A\subset X$ such that $A$ is not compact.

I suppose that every subset of $X$ is compact.

There is a Countably dense subset $E$ of $X$, then $\overline{E}=X$ and $E$ is closed, now $E=X$, that is to say, $X$ is a Countably set...

I don't know how to follow the proof...

Do you have any help with this?

Comment: You have at least two errors.  There is a countable dense subset $E$  of $X$, but $\overline E$ need not be $X$.  $X$ could be all the irrationals.  The rational multiples of $\sqrt 2$ are a countable dense subset, but $\overline E=\mathbb R \neq X$  We were never given that $X$ is closed.  Also $X$ need not be countable, as the same example shows.

Comment: Your edit is also incorrect.  $E$ need not be closed, though $\overline E$ is.  We do have $\overline E \cap X = X$, but that does not prove that $X$ is countable.  Clearly it need not be, as $X$ could be $(1,2)$, for example.  It is neither countable nor compact.

Comment: $E$  is compact, I suppose that every subset of X is compact, then $E$ is closed ...

Comment: Then $E \cap X$ may well not be $X$.  Let $X$ be $[1,2]$ and $E$ be the rationals in the interval.

Comment: You’ve not phrased it clearly, but you can in fact use such an argument to show that $X$ must be countable if every subset of it is compact. $\Bbb R^n$ is hereditarily separable, so $X$ has a countable dense subset $E$. $E$ is compact and therefore closed, so $X=\operatorname{cl}E=E$, and $X$ is therefore countable. But you don’t need to make this argument, as the two answers already given show.

Comment: If  I suppose that every subset of $X$ is compact, then $X$ is compact, then $\overline{E} \subset X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that every subset of $X$ is compact. As we're in a metric space, all compact subsets are closed, so all subsets of $X$ are closed (both in $X$ and in $\Bbb R^m$). So all subsets of $X$ are open in $X$ (their complement is closed in $X$) and so $\{x\}, x \in X$ is an open cover of $X$ which has a finite subcover by compactness of $X$. It follows that $X$ is finite already. But we're given $X$ is infinite, contradiction.

Comment: This is a lovely argument. I would delete the last sentence, however: this is a straightforward proof of the contrapositive of the original statement, not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @GregMartin well, the OP started that way, so I followed suit. Thx BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_k)$ be as sequence in $X$ consisting of distinct points. If It is unbounded there is  a subsequence $(x_{k_i})$ such that  $\|x_{k_i}\| \to \infty$ and $\{x_{k_i}: i=1,2,..\}$ is a subset which is not compact.  If it is bounded then there is a susequence $(x_{k_i})$ converging to some point $x$ and $\{x_{k_i}: i=1,2,...\}\setminus \{x\}$  is not compact since it is not closed.

Comment: The second half of the argument is not quite valid: the subsequence might be $\{0,1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\dots\}$, for example. But the subsequence, with $x$ taken out if it appears, should work.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can streamline this: If $(x_k)$ has no convergent subsequence then $A=\{x_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ is not compact. If $(x_k)$ has a subsequence converging to $x$ then $A \setminus  \{x\}$ is not closed.